# How to publish a package that needs a token/key to operate

Tags: python

I'm working on publishing my very first package on PyPi, which in order to operate needs a OPENAI key.

How would I go to publishing it without making my key public?

I have tried to look for ways to to this (ex.: [readme.ai](https://github.com/eli64s/readme-ai), but I haven't been able to figure out how.

Comment: You would include in your documentation instructions for how people working with your code could configure their own openapi key.

Comment: But this project ([readme.ai](https://github.com/eli64s/readme-ai)), specifically, doesn't require me to have an API key, it runs on the owners api key. And it is not public

Comment: If you're publishing it on PyPi it sure seems to be public.

Comment: Are you trying to distribute a *library* (code that other people should `import` for their own project), or an *application* (code that people should run at the command line to solve a practical problem)?

Comment: I want to distribute it as an application @KarlKnechtel

Comment: I see. And do you intend that your users should get their own API key first? Or are you trying to make the program request one on their behalf?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The idea was to have have my key do the work for the users. But from what I can see, it's not possible to do it without making the key public

Comment: The entire reason why they require an API in the first place, is so they can track how much the API is used by a given person, and either limit that or charge for it. Even if other people could somehow use your key without finding out what the key is, it would defeat the purpose of having a key (from the API operator's perspective).

Answer (score 3):

The package you linked does require your own API key.
[image: 1]

If want to release your package, you need to give the user a method to call such as

```py
import myLib
myLib.set_api_key(key)
```

Then use this key as the default key for making any calls to the API. Optionally, you can also allow `key` as an optional argument for any functions that make calls to the API.

The only way for you to do this without making a user input their own key is to allow it to be made through your key, which is *probably* not what you want. If it's a free key, describe how to obtain one in your library's documentation. If it's a key using paid credits or that you pay for, you almost **definitely** do not want to do that, but I didn't need to tell you that.

Comment: I did see this item in the docs, but when I used it I didn't have to setup the key, which was the reason why I assumed it had a default key implemented and hidden.